# my twig variables do not show me any data from a OneToOne relationship symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, one-to-one

I have three entities in my system: Doctor, Planning and PlanningLine.
A doctor with a schedule and a schedule has several lines of schedules (which goes from Monday to Sunday). And I already have data stored in my tables.Thus I would like for a doctor, in his details page that he is displayed a chart of his schedule of days when it is available or not.
But when I do my twig test, I have nothing displayed on the page.

**Entity Planning**

```
  /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\PlanningLine", mappedBy="planning", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $planningLines;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $medecin;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->planningLines = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Entity PlanningLine**

```
 class PlanningLine
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Planning", inversedBy="planningLines", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $planning;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="day", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $day;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_hour", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $startHour;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_hour", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $endHour;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isFree", type="boolean")
 */
private $isFree;
}
```

**Entity Doctor**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Planning")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $planning;
```

**My view in Twig**

```
    <div class="box_general_3">
                    <div class="indent_title_in">
                        <i class="pe-7s-clock"></i>
                        <h3>DISPONIBILITÉS</h3>
                        <p>Les horaires de disponibilité du medecin.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper_indent">
                        <table class = "table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>

                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    DEBUT
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    FIN
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead> 

                              {%  for plan in medecin.planning %}
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     {% if plan.planningLines.isFree is defined %}

                                    <strong>{{ plan.planningLines.day }}</strong>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ plan.starthour }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ plan.endhour }}
                                </td>



                            </tr>

                                {% else %}

                            <tr class = "unavailable">
                                <td>
                                    <strong>{{ plan.day }}</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ plan.starthour }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ plan.endhour }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                        {% endif %}
                            </tbody>
                                    {% endfor %}
                        </table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your relations and defining a  fetch="EAGER" in your entity Doctor ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Planning",mappedBy="medecin",fetch="EAGER")
  */
private $planning;
```

and also :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin",inversedBy="planning")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $medecin;
```

Otherwise you can write a custom request in your repository with join on planning and planning lines ...
Also

```
/**
```

* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $medecin;

is useless as joinColumn are nullable by default...